# Filter time-series by time span

Tags: kql

is there a way to filter a time series according to timespan in other columns, without expanding it?

Example:

| timeSeries | ValueSeries | startTime | endTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [t1, t2, t3, t4] | [1, 2, 3, 4 ] | t1 | t3 |
| [t1, t2, t3, t4] | [6, 7, 8, 9 ] | t2 | t4 |

Expected result:

| timeSeries | ValueSeries | startTime | endTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [t1, t2, t3] | [1, 2, 3] | t1 | t3 |
| [t2, t3, t4] | [7, 8, 9] | t2 | t4 |

Comment: Why "without expanding it"? I assume you refer to the use of *mv-expend*.

Comment: It is not clear how you data actually looks like (is timeSeries constructed from timespan?) . Please provide sample data that matches your use-case.

Comment: Apologies. timeSeries constucted of datetime, not timespan. But the solution provided can apply to both cases. Thanks דודו !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datatable(timeSeries:dynamic, ValueSeries:dynamic, startTime:timespan, endTime:timespan)
[
    dynamic([1m, 2m, 3m, 4m]), dynamic([1, 2, 3, 4 ]), 1m, 3m
   ,dynamic([1m, 2m, 3m, 4m]), dynamic([6, 7, 8, 9 ]), 2m, 4m
]
| mv-apply timeSeries to typeof(timespan), ValueSeries to typeof(long) on
  (
      where timeSeries between (startTime .. endTime)
    | summarize timeSeries  = make_list(timeSeries)
               ,ValueSeries = make_list(ValueSeries)
  )
```

| startTime | timeSeries | endTime | ValueSeries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:01:00 | ["00:01:00","00:02:00","00:03:00"] | 00:03:00 | [1,2,3] |
| 00:02:00 | ["00:02:00","00:03:00","00:04:00"] | 00:04:00 | [7,8,9] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42RwWoCMRCG7wv7Dv8xgVHQllaFPkVLLyIldkcNTbLLJla2%20PDNxrrN4sUJc/nn/5KZSaVCPFvDImjLr9xq9quqc8rqT8K7Mscb0QfVhrfoXvWIb5QjsKtGiiyLdVkgxh8m1jNLmMd8iPloN5KyUqzEQtTR67PkSjjdgz8RngkLwjLh8%20Qoi01ZnGG/J6ppTIf/8RBqhK7heieGdkejZgZTu71E7fpmxGUg4HTglvMLtxxOzA5iWA2m0%20tO5AU7wx%20tVa3%20GaF4gVVf/GG0D9kXyOtbQ1DeYA5leqLkLx7%20N%20jTAQAA)